# Date format to dd/mm/yyyy in a single object

Tags: javascript, date

I know that date format "dd/mm/yyyy" can be achieved like this:

```
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
var month = (d.getMonth() +1);
var year = d.getFullYear();

document.write("Today is " +day+ "/" +month+ "/" +year+ "<br>");
```

Date picker

```
var x = new Date(document.getElementById("dateSelection"));
```

However how can I convert those to a single date object so I can then compare it against date picker in a simple statement like this:

```
if (d > x)
{
   document.write("Date from the past");
}
else if (d < x)
{
   document.write("Date from the future");
}
else
{
   document.write("Date equals today's date");
}
```

Thanks for help I'm novice at this.

Comment: you don't need to compare the formats, you compare date **objects**. A date object is a "date" regardless of the format

Comment: So, does the code you have not work?  I see nothing wrong with your `if(d > x)`.

Comment: No I get "Date from the past" no matter what I select.

Comment: What is `dateSelection`?  You do realize you are passing the element to the `Date` constructor, not its value, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the `dateSelection` element to `new Date`, not its value.  `Date` wants a string as its parameter, not a DOMElement.

Try this:

```
var x = new Date(document.getElementById("dateSelection").value);
```

Comment: This has sorted my error, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a handy dandy prototype to convert the string to a date:

```
String.prototype.toDate=function(){
   var mo = parseInt(this.substr(0,2)) -1
   var dy = this.substr(3,2)
   var yr = this.substr(6,4)
   var dt  = new Date(yr, mo, dy, 0, 0, 0, 0)
   return dt
}

var s = '01/01/2014'
var d = s.toDate()
```

Now you have a date and can do date comparisons.